# Serialization error in Weka 3.8.x

Tags: java, scala, serialization, weka

I am using `WEKA 3.8 API` from my Scala project. When I try to save a model (already build classifier) using `SerializationHelper.write(fullFilename, model)` I get the following exception. Same code is ok with Weka version 3.6.

I would say that the problem is that the `UpperSymmDenseMatrix` is a class that does not implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface.
Any tip on how to solve the issue?
Thanks in advance

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: no.uib.cipr.matrix.UpperSymmDenseMatrix
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
```

Comment: java.io.NotSerializableException [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html): `Thrown when an instance is required to have a Serializable interface`. One of your classes is not serializable, try to use case classes if you're not creating a lot of them.

Comment: Yes, you are right but the not serializable class is `no.uib.cipr.matrix.UpperSymmDenseMatrix` which is not part of my codebase. It is inside matrix-toolkits-java.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

I managed to find out that the problem is indeed caused by a modified version of *matrix-toolkits-java*. Weka 3.8.1 comes with a copy of *matrix-toolkits-java* in version 1.0.4 that is slightly larger compared to the one from maven central repository:

```
<groupId>com.googlecode.matrix-toolkits-java</groupId>
<artifactId>mtj</artifactId>
<version>1.0.4</version>
```

**Solution**

Including *mtj.jar* from **weka-src.jar** instead of the maven dependency solved the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try!

Comment: This took care of the problem. Thanks!